# The get method is overriding my url variable

Tags: php

After clicking the submit button in a form using the GET method, the new variables overrides my old one:

Before submit:

```
www.example.com/?a=product
```

a - represents the page, after submit:

```
www.example.com/?brand=1&maxprice=200
```

So the a varible disapear the page is reloaded and redirects me to the home page which is the default case if a value is not founded..

I tried few options on the form action such as:

```
?a=product // lead me to the result I showed above
?a=product& // same result as above
a=product // leads to www.example.com/a=product... unknown page
```

Comment: Why aren't you using POST for your form? This would fix your original problem, as well as the fact you'd be doing things The Right Way then

Comment: since it's a form that filters some products so if someone will copy the url (while i'm using the post method) and send it to someone he wont see the filtered page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to do this but you could add a hidden input element in your form that is named 'a' and has a value of $_GET['a'], so that 'a' is posted with the form like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['a']);?>"/>
```

Comment: ESCAPING is missing! With that code you just created a very nice attack method for cross site scripting!

Comment: XSS hole, you need to escape $_GET["a"];

Comment: It's working, i'll mark your answer as correct as soon as possible. Btw why you don't understand why I'm doing that?

Comment: mysql_real_escape is for MySQL only, you can easily trick it in HTML attributes. htmlspecialchars in XML mode is the way to go.,

Comment: I wrote the basic code, whichever sanitization function the developer wants to use is up to them...I build a custom one and run the vars through that normally.

Comment: You are wrong. Sanitization is not needed here, and the escaping needed is crystalclear: You are writing arbitrary strings into HTML, so the escaping must be matching THAT context. If not: Bad things happen.

Comment: Thanks for being negative about my answer, why don't you contribute constructively by telling us how YOU would do it instead?

Comment: You didn't seem to realize what this is all about. So effectively you are currently learning how to escape strings in HTML properly, which is a good thing. You haven't come to the right conclusion right now. Why should I shortcut your learning curve?

Comment: I know exactly what this is about thank you. It's not shortcutting, it's helping...I thought that is what Stackoverflow is for?

Comment: it's working i just wrote: <input type="hidden" name="a" value="product"/>

Comment: Imri, your way will work if 'a' is always going to be equal to 'product', but if that's the case then I'd store that somewhere else rather than passing a constant around all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP 5.4, use that

```
$encoding="UTF-8"; // Or whatever encoding you are using
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['a'],ENT_XML1 | ENT_COMPAT,$encoding);?>"/>
```

Else just use htmlspecialchars without ENT_XML1 | ENT_COMPAT and a str_replace on " and .

```
$encoding="UTF-8"; // Or whatever encoding you are using
$v=$_GET["a"];
$v=str_replace("\"","",$v);
$v=str_replace("\\","",$v);
$v=htmlspecialchars($v,ENT_QUOTES,$encding);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="a" value="' . $v . '"/>'
```

For the foreach loop, look at the other answers.

Comment: `htmlentities()` without mentioning the character encoding is a bad thing. Why not use `htmlspecialchars()`?

Comment: Only if you don't set the correct default encoding, which is in 5.4 UTF-8. In 5.3 or sooner you have to manually set it. I'll add it.

Comment: You cannot know the currently used encoding, and messing anything else with UTF-8 is as bad as messing UTF-8 with ISO-8859-1. For this to be a universal answer, you should make that explicit - and then remove the hint suggesting this will only work in PHP 5.4.

Comment: The constant ENT_XML1 is only avaliable in 5.4 or later (from php.net): 5.4.0  The constants ENT_SUBSTITUTE, ENT_DISALLOWED, ENT_HTML401, ENT_XML1, ENT_XHTML and ENT_HTML5 were added.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to use the POST method for your form, then on the page that the form gets submitted to, use $_POST.  Your $_GET for a should still work.